# ReduxでdispatchしpayloadからのuseEffectを実行しその中のuseStateのセット関数で更新した値で判定する方法

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

タイトルが分かりにくくて申し訳ありません。

useStateのセット関数で更新した値をすぐに参照したのですが、更新前の値が取れてしまいます。
useStateの更新はすぐに実行されないというのは知っています。

#### やりたいこと

イベント内でuseStateの更新後の値をすぐに参照したいです。

#### 概要

イベント内でリストを再取得し、再取得後のリスト件数（multipleList.length）で判定をしたいです。
今は更新前の値が取れる為、１ステップ処理が遅れている状態です。

#### コード

```
const [ multipleList, setMultipleList ] = useState<selectAddressList[]>([])

// ★１
useEffect(() => {
 const setNewSelAddrList = () => {
  if (selAddressList && selAddressList.length > 0){
   const newList = [...selAddressList]
  
   // ここで更新後の住所リストが格納されているのは確認済
　 setMultipleList(newList);
　}
 }
 setNewSelAddrList();
}, [selAddressList])

// コンボボックス変更イベント
const onChangeAddr3 = async(rowData:string) => {

 // rowDataには、郵便番号が入っている
 if (rowData != ''){

  // 郵便番号から住所一覧を取得
  await dispatch(fetchAsyncSelectedAddressList(rowData.toString()))        // ★２
　    
  // ★更新された住所リストの件数で判定したい★
  if (multipleList.length == 0){
   ＸＸＸＸＸＸＸ
  }

 }
};
```

#### 補足

★１　住所リスト（selAddressList）が変更されたタイミングでイベント発火。
　　　　fetchAsyncSelectedAddressListでselAddressListが更新されます。
★２　ReduxのSliceを通して、APIからデータ取得し、住所リスト（selAddressList）を更新している

宜しくお願い致します。